# Convert My Code SQL to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Kindly convert my SQL to LINQ. I'm really desperate. It includes multiple filtering (2).

```
    SELECT     dbo.EmployeeAccess.EmpNo, 
               dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.LNameByFName, 
               dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.GroupName, 
               dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.Role, 
               dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.Active, 
               dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.EmpNo AS Expr4, 
               dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.RoleID
     FROM      dbo.EmployeeAccess 
     INNER JOIN dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers 
     ON         dbo.EmployeeAccess.GroupID = dbo.View_SystemAdminMembers.GroupID
     WHERE     (dbo.EmployeeAccess.EmpNo = '50')
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: An example is given on this link http://itworksonmymachine.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/sql-to-linq-cheat-sheet/

Comment: And this https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll try to implement. Unfortunately, my linqpad doesn't convert my SQL statement, only have C#, VB, and F# options. I guess I was looking at the wrong place there and not sure if I've looked for it hard enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
var result =from e in context.EmployeeAccess 
            join v in context.View_SystemAdminMembers on e.GroupID equals v.GroupID 
            Where e.EmpNo == 50
            select new {  e.EmpNo,v.LNameByFName,v.GroupName,v.Role,v.Active,a.RoleID,v.EmpNo as VEmpNo };
```

Note : context is your DB Context object.

Let me know if any concern.

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = (from ea in DbContext.EmployeeAccess
               join sam in DbContext.View_SystemAdminMembers on ea.GroupId equals sam.GroupId
               where ea.EmpNo = '50'
               select new {
                 ea.EmpNo,
                 sam.LNameByFName,
                 sam.GroupName,
                 sam.Role,
                 sam.Active,
                 Expr4 = sam.EmpNo,
                 sam.RoleID
               };
```

You didnt mention what your database context was, you'll have to fill that in yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var res = (from x in ctx.EmployeeAccess
             join y in ctx.View_SystemAdminMembers on x.GroupId equals y.groupId
             where x.EmpNo = '50'
             select new
             {
                 x.EmpNo,
                 y.LNameByFName,
                 y.GroupName,
                 y.Role,
                 y.Active,
                 Expr4 = y.EmpNo,
                 y.RoleID
             });
```

**Note**: do **NOT** use `=` when joining, but `equals`.